# In Django Admin, how to explicitly display some fields on the same line while displaying all the others by default

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Our Django admin forms are getting long, and it would enhance usability to group some fields on a single line (as they are logically tied).

We are aware of grouping fields in a tuple and use it as an element of the `ModelAdmin.fields` tuple attribute.

```
class FlatPageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = (('url', 'title'), 'content')
```

Which displays "url" and "title" on the same line.

Is it possible to achieve a similar explicit display of some fields on a single line, while having all the other (non-excluded) fields shown, like when there are no `fields` or `fieldsets` attribute on the `ModelAdmin` ?